# Name for something that is being advertised

Tags: meaning, nouns

What would be the correct term for a thing that is being advertised?

I am looking for something less generic than *Product* but can still be used across different business domains (so not something like *Car*).

Comment: "advertised products" or "our products as advertised"

Comment: I think the most general term (product) is the only thing that can be used here. The subject of the adverisement is directly related to the business, so in order to apply to all businesses, it would probably need to have a general term like product to apply. You might be able to differentiate based on the use of the product (cleaning products vs lawn products) but even then you'd be narrowing the field and not encompassing a wide range of people.

Comment: i would say 'advertee' but i'm not going to

Comment: or maybe 'advertand'.  But that would mean "that which is to be adverted".

Comment: "Worthless junk" would probably work, except that it's two words.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like *product or service* would work, because pretty much anything someone sells would be one or the other.

Another suggestion is *commodity*, which [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commodity) defines as "something that is bought and sold" (and therefore advertised).

**EDIT**: To stress that a product or service is being advertised, you could refer to it as "the subject of the advertisement."

Comment: Yes, but *product* by itself does not imply that it is being advertised.

Answer (score 1):

*Promoted item* may work, or *promoted* as preface to either *service* or *product.* Will that do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

What about *Promotional Item*?

Or if you were speaking less formally, you could use something universally known as generic like "widget".

Answer (score 0):

[Offering](https://www.google.com/search?q=offering&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8):

> a thing produced or manufactured for entertainment or sale.

`"Hollywood's latest offerings for the European market."`